# Изменить отображение очереди проверок

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, очередь-проверок

Не знаю, у одного ли у меня такая проблема, но я как ни зайду на сайт, очередь проверок, которая для меня доступна, всегда пуста. Для проверки данного факта приходиться открывать, точнее нажимать на значок проверки, что неудобно.

Получается найти свободную проверку очень редко. У некоторых бывает до 26 проверок в день, а я больше трех никогда не делал.

Мои предложения:

1. Отображать количество свободных проверок.
2. Изменить интерфейс (например изменять цвет кнопки)
3. Оставить все как есть (неудобно только мне)

Comment: Про какую очередь идёт речь, случайно не про "запоздалые ответы"? Так там крайне редко прилетает на проверку.

Comment: @AK я про первые сообщения

Comment: В этой очереди тоже нечасто проходят сообщения. По 26 проверок быть не может - максимально возможное 20 для любой очереди. И людей по 20 проверок не так уж и много -- это постоянные участники очередей проверок, которые много времени проводят в очередях проверок. Если хотите много проверок - либо постоянно жать F5, либо заходите во время когда мало проверяющих - либо крайне рано, либо крайне поздно по MSK, именно это время меньше всего проверяющих онлайн.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Спасибо, что помогаете сделать сайт лучше!

В очередях проверок в принципе сложилась следующая ситуация: крайне мало проверяющих рук в очереди на закрытие вопросов, прямо дефицит. (В зависимости от вашего уровня репутации вы можете увидеть там и по сто и по триста заданий на проверку) И есть очереди, в которых задания появляются редко и заторов там практически не бывает.

Если есть желание помочь с очередями проверок - набирайте достаточно репутации (3k+) для доступа к этой очереди и присоединяйтесь, ещё одна пара рук нам точно не помешает!

На текущий момент в тех очередях, про которые вы пишете - очень низкое количество заданий на проверку. С учётом того, что проверяющие в основном находятся в московском часовом поясе то большинство проверок в некоторые часы выполняются крайне быстро - и если вы в это же время хотите проверку, то можете просто не успеть буквально на считанные минуты и даже секунды. Можете попробовать зайти пока Москва ещё/уже спит, но это не всем удобно.

С количеством свободных проверок всё совсем непросто.

Во-первых, даже текущая логика вывода информации туманна (непонятно, когда загорается красным): официальной информации нет, а попытки эту логику разгадать не увенчались успехом. Можете поискать в чате и на мете сообщения о странности очередей проверок - их хватает.

Во-вторых, разработчики движка so редко впиливают подобные улучшения: ресурсов не так много и в основном делаются потребности бизнесовые, типа teams. С учётом того, что каждый сайт сети работает на одном и том же движке, но не всегда на одной и той же версии - трогать работающее не такая простая задача.

Так что я скептически смотрю на возможные доработки в этом плане, гораздо вероятнее, что их оставят как есть.

Если же будет желание предложить какие-либо изменения - попробуйте написать через форму обратной связи или на MSE.